# How to add rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange plugin to RabbitMQ running docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I would like to add the "rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange" plugin to my docker installation.
Also, I want the Plugin to stay there after I reboot the RabbitMQ container.

The installation script I use is:

```
docker run -d -h docker01.docker                               \
       --add-host=docker01.docker:192.168.1.11                \
       --name rabbit                                            \
       -p "4370:4370"                                           \
       -p "5672:5672"                                           \
       -p "15672:15672"                                         \
       -p "25672:25672"                                         \
       -p "35197:35197"                                         \
       -e "RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME=true"                          \
       -e "ERL_EPMD_PORT=4370"                                    \
       -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE="rabbitcookie"                     \
       -e RABBITMQ_NODENAME="master"                             \
       -e "RABBITMQ_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log"          \
       -v /data/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq                                 \
       -v /data/rabbitmq/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq                             \
       rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
```

Is it possible to add that plugin to this above installation?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819237/how-to-add-plugin-to-rabbitmq-docker-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add plugin to RabbitMQ docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819237/how-to-add-plugin-to-rabbitmq-docker-image)

Comment: For this plugin, you can use Docker image masstransit/rabbitmq, which is regularly updated and includes the plugin. https://hub.docker.com/r/masstransit/rabbitmq

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should create your rabbitmq image with this plugin to be allowed to use.

I found this repo [1] with a dockerfile to build a image. ( I had a problem because the new version has v before the names, pay attention to this fact)

This is my dockerfile that I created based on this repo [1]

```
ARG PLUGIN_VERSION=3.12.0
ARG BASE_VERSION=3.12

FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS builder

ARG PLUGIN_VERSION

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl
RUN mkdir -p /plugins && \
    curl -fsSL \
    -o "/plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-${PLUGIN_VERSION}.ez" \
    https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/v${PLUGIN_VERSION}/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-${PLUGIN_VERSION}.ez

FROM rabbitmq:${BASE_VERSION}-management-alpine

ARG PLUGIN_VERSION

COPY --from=builder --chown=rabbitmq:rabbitmq \
    /plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-${PLUGIN_VERSION}.ez \
    $RABBITMQ_HOME/plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-${PLUGIN_VERSION}.ez

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

[1] https://github.com/heidiks/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange